# Which type assign to the variable "error"?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've the following TypeScript code:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const fs = require('fs')

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{


    fs.readFile("./data/users.json", "utf8", (error: any,data: any) =>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            return;
         }
         console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })

})
```

How can I use the `error` element without specifying the type `any`? I want the error to be the same as I would have used if I had written this code in NodeJS.. How can I do it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Suggestion to give it a read https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-import-use-fs-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of readfile is below.

```
function readFile(path: number | fs.PathLike, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void): void
```

What you can do is

```
import fs from 'fs';

fs.readFile('',(err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null) =>{
    err.code
});
```

When you hover on function your code editor will show the type definition of any function.

Comment: That code will have an error - more precise is ```NodeJS.ErrnoException | null```